# What is my pizza cutter's handle made from, and how do I stop it from staining everything it touches?

Tags: equipment, pizza, maintenance

A while back, I bought an ordinary-looking pizza cutter with a dull grey handle.  However, I soon found out the hard way that the handle is made from some weird metal or alloy that reacts with water, staining everything it touches black:

[image]

"Water" here includes even slightly moist or sweaty hands, making this a real pain to use.  **What is this stuff and how do I stop it from staining?**  And for extra credit, why on earth would you make a hand-held kitchen utensil from it?!

Comment: Is it heavy enough to be cast iron? Cast iron teapots do that, it's highly annoying.

Comment: I don't think so: it's pretty heavy, but not that heavy?  Also, the original color was a dull medium grey (see eg. the light patch on the left side near the bottom of the handle), whereas all the cast iron I've ever seen is black or close to it.

Comment: If it's that big of an issue, I recommend trashing it and buying a new one... they aren't that expensive and the ATK top rated one from [OXO](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00004OCJN/?tag=atkequippilot-20) is $13.

Comment: Spray painting the handle should solve the problem, but it would probably be cheaper to just to get a new cutter like Catija suggested.

Comment: Looks like molded plastic to me. Likely degrading from too many trips thru the dishwashwer. The plasticizer's been leeched and the handle is crumbling. Get a new one.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger No, it's a metal of some kind, not plastic. And the staining started almost immediately, after the first or second wash.

Comment: Do you remember the brand? Knowing that is the most likely way of finding out what it's made out of.  I did an image search for these cutters and couldn't find anything identical to it in the images or on Amazon.  Brand and/or the country it was purchased in will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mystery solved**!  At Catija's prompting, I managed to dig up the cutter on the website of the shop I bought it from, the [Chef's Hat](http://www.chefshat.com.au) in Melbourne, Australia:

[image]

[CUTTER PIZZA W/ALUM HANDLE 95MM S/ST](http://www.chefshat.com.au/product/405-cutter-pizza-w-alum-handle-95mm-s-st) ($6.60)

So turns out the handle is **aluminum** (aluminium), which can be discolored black if the alloy is not dishwasher-safe, which this clearly wasn't.  Time to ask a new question about what, if anything, I can do to fix it!

Comment: So can you polish it and stop putting it in the DW?

Comment: I'd see if you can take the blade off, then scower with steel wool, spray with a metal spray primer, and some new color/top coat. A clear coat would probably make it dishwasher safe. 

The three cans of spray paint, and a spray can trigger probably cost more than a replacement.

Comment: Independently of the alloy used, cutting implements don't go into the dishwasher, it blunts them in no time. Anything except for a butter knife should be washed by hand. I would guess that this is why the manufacturer didn't care to choose a dishwasher safe alloy for a pizza wheel.

Comment: for $6.60...buy a new one...May I recommend [this pizza cutter from Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/RSVP-World-Class-Pizza-Cutter/dp/B0000E2GT5/ref=sr_1_3?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1428975110&sr=1-3&keywords=pizza+cutter) I have one and it is great. [IMHO]